# How can I get more colors in Python's curses?

Tags: python, terminal, ncurses

I'm working on a project for school right now, and I'm using curses. Although, I am a bit disappointed on the restrict of colors. The colorama module has LOTS more colors, and they work on my Terminal, so I know my terminal is capable of lots of colors. Although, in Curses, we only have

```
COLOR_BLACK
COLOR_RED
COLOR_GREEN
COLOR_YELLOW
COLOR_BLUE
COLOR_MAGENTA
COLOR_CYAN
COLOR_WHITE
```

It would be REALLY nice if there where more colors.

Note: Colorama gives ANSI escape codes, and doesn't work with Curses, so no shortcut there.

Comment: That's just the way terminals have been made. Be thankful you don't have to use a monochrome monitor. :) However, some modern terminals do support 256 color, and urxvt has it as a compile-time option.

Comment: What terminal are you using and what is the TERM environment variable set to?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551558/how-to-use-terminal-color-palette-with-curses

Answer (score 7):

A color in curses is just a number from `0` to `curses.COLORS - 1`. Those you listed are just the *named constants* curses provide you.

Curses supports 256 colors just fine, but it only enables that ***if your terminal identifies itself as a 256-color capable terminal*** via `TERM` environmental variable.

While most modern terminals *do* support 256 colors for years, such as Gnome Terminal and Xterm, many still do not report as such.

If you run your program using `env TERM=xterm-256color yourprogram`, curses will enable 256 colors, and it will work fine *as long as your terminal actually supports it!*

If it does work, change your terminal to automatically set its `TERM` appropriately.

Recommended further reading:

http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/term-strings/

http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/256-colour-terminals/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181766/4919

https://askubuntu.com/a/578798/11015

Comment: Note that there are also restrictions on colour pairs as documented in the [FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_16MegaColors).  In short, you can use up to 256 colour pairs on ncurses 5 and 32767 on ncurses 6.

Answer (score 5):

[Urwid](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/urwid) supports [256 colour terminals](https://excess.org/urwid/examples.html): [palette_test.py](http://excess.org/urwid/browser/examples/palette_test.py).

I recommend it as a superior alternative to the curses module (if using the curses module isn't a requirement of the project).

Comment: IMHO there is no need to change the module, as `curses` supports 256 colors just fine if your `TERM` is set correctly, and it's available out of the box with Python as part of its Standard Library.

Comment: 2 of the 3 links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub there is a free to use, study, modify and re-distribute High Level GUI library, at "https://github.com/rigordo959/tsWxGTUI_PyVx_Repository".

It is implemented in Python 2x & 3x using the "curses" Low Level GUI package.

Your application programs can be programmed using a character-mode subset of the pixel-mode "wxPython" High Level GUI API. It supports displays with keyboard and mouse input and various terminal emulators including the color xterms (8-color with 64-color pairs and 16-color with 256-color pairs) and non-color vt100/vt220.

It includes Python modules that can configure up to 256 curses colors. However curses cannot handle more than 256 color-pairs which means no more than 16 colors if the application will need to handle the 256 color pairs to expose or hide text.

Answer (score -1):

The [Fabulous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fabulous/) package provides 256 colour support but it is not linked to ncurses.  Although, I am sure you can mix the two.